# One user needs to click OK to applet security warning 6 times

Tags: java, security, applet

We have an applet that is interacting with a printer that shows a security warning once for all users except one.  This user has to click "OK" for the security warning 6 times.  Here's a screenshot of the warning:

[image: Applet Security Warning]

From what I've gathered, there are two approaches to getting around the warning:
1. Sign the applet
2. Update the user's java security file under their user profile on their hard drive

What are the pros and cons of using either of these approaches?  Is one of them the preferred approach?  Is one simpler and quicker to implement than the other?

**Edit I**
It looks like we're going to go down the route of signing the applet.
Is it possible to use the same certificate that is on the web server to sign the applet?

Comment: What happens when the user ticks the 'Always allow..' check-box?  I would expect it to remember that decision for the run of the applet, but not when it is reloaded.  How much access to the problem machine do you have (e.g. 'administrator access')?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I'm waiting to hear back from the user on exactly what happens and then I'll update the question.  I know that the user IS clicking the check box but I think that there's a different message that gets returned on the subsequent alerts.  Also, I can't get onto the user's machine unfortunately (BTW, they only have non-admin privs on the machine).

Comment: Might be worth taking a stack dump of when this appears. You can do this programmatically within the applet for your own threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible some policy enforcement in IE is preventing the "Always allow..." checkbox from saving that choice.

As for the pros/cons, as I see it:

1. Signing your app: Requires a certificate.  If its self-signed, you will have other errors most likely in the browser, but I think you have avoid this by including your custom cert, or the certificate root, in the broswer.
2. Updating user's security file: Never really done this, but it seems like a nightmare to maintain if you have a lot of users...plus it seems like a lot of manual work.